# Allow firewall connections using Applescript

Tags: macos, ios, ios-simulator, applescript, firewall

I am trying to automate running an ios app in the simulator using Applescript. Whenever the application is first launched I get the firewall pop up asking to Deny or Allow connections to my app and I would like to Allow connections in the same script. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the application to the list of exceptions in the Firewall tab of the Security System Preference?

Comment: Yes the problem is during application development on the iPad a new application is created each time a code change is made so that exception list keeps growing with a new version of the application. All with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "Deny" and "Allow" are from the firewall application LittleSnitch. So the easiest solution would be to turn it off when you're testing your simulator program.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have LittleSnitch installed but keep getting these dialogs from the OS X Firewall. As I am running as non-admin user I have to enter a password each time I recompile my program. Any further ideas on this issue? This gets tiresome after some time.

Comment: @MKroehnert I am willing to unaccept this answer and accept a better one since I do not have little snitch installed either. It was a result of the OSX firewall but I just ended up disabling it.

Comment: @Joe: unfortunately I do not have a solution right now. Otherwise I would be more than glad to share it with you.